# Executing Lua callback with a delay in C++

Tags: c++, function, lua, callback

What I want to do is to execute a `createEvent` method, which first argument is the callback that should be executed in C++ after a certain delay (second argument):

```
createEvent(function() print("Event has been fired.") end, 10)
```

When the event ends, the callback is never being executed.

This is what I have on the stack before calling `lua_pcall`:

```
nil, boolean, userdata
```

How should this be done properly?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
struct LuaCallbackEvent {
    int32_t delay;
    int32_t ref;

    LuaCallbackEvent() : delay(0), ref(0) { }
};

int32_t _lua_createEvent(lua_State* L) {
    // Callback delay
    auto delay = lua_tonumber(L, 2);
    // Lua callback reference
    auto lua_cb = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

    LuaCallbackEvent cb;
    cb.delay = delay;
    cb.ref = lua_cb;

    EventManager::instance().CreateLuaCallback(cb);
    return 0;
}

// Gets called when specfic time has elapsed
void ExecuteLuaCallback(LuaCallbackEvent* ev) {
    if (!L) {
        LERR << "No state";
        return;
    }

    // Retrieve callback by the reference
    lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, ev->ref);

    // Execute callback
    lua_pcall(L, 1, LUA_MULTRET, 0);

    // Unset reference
    luaL_unref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, ev->ref);
}
```

Comment: I don't see your code, but you should either do check in loop or implement some kind of C++-side callback (if no mainloop is used).